# How to improve the defined command as the statements?

Tags: large-symbols

First a minimal working sample is as follow.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\tikzdottedwedgesource{%
\tikz[baseline=-0.25em, line cap=round, dash pattern=on 0pt off 3\pgflinewidth]{%
\draw[line width=0.05375em] (0.00em,0.34em) -- (-0.204em,-0.288em);%
\draw[line width=0.05375em] (0.00em,0.34em) -- (0.204em,-0.288em);%
}}
\newcommand*\dottedwedgesource{\mathbin{\mkern1mu\tikzdottedwedgesource\mkern1mu}}

\newcommand*\macro@dottedbigwedge[2]{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{%
            \sbox\z@{$#1\bigwedge$}%
            \resizebox{!}{0.9\dimexpr\ht\z@+\dp\z@}{\raisebox{0\depth}{$\m@th#1\dottedwedgesource$}}%
    }}%
    \vphantom{\bigwedge}%
}
\newcommand*\dottedbigwedge{%
    \DOTSB\mathop{\mathpalette\macro@dottedbigwedge\relax}\slimits@%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[
\dottedbigwedge_x^y\phi=\bigwedge_x^y\phi.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see I defined a large operator `\dashedbigwedge`. My question is **is there anyway to make the command involve no `\bigwedge` while it doesn't change the output of the command?**.

Comment: You want that the symbol has the same dimensions as `\bigwedge`: how could you know them without measuring `\bigwedge`?

Comment: @egreg I just want them to be large operators.

Comment: There's no law telling us what the size of a large operator should be. Different fonts may have different sizes. Commonly, all large operators in a math font will have the same size, but you have to measure at least one of them.